# How can I duplicate a calendar entry on Microsoft Outlook web interface?

Tags: outlook-on-the-web, outlook.com-calendar

How can I duplicate a calendar entry on Microsoft Outlook web interface?

Use case: I had a meeting last week. I want to schedule a meeting for next week with the same information (i.e., same guests, same location, same agenda), just different time.

I don't want to schedule a reoccurring meeting, and I don't want to move last week's meeting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can duplicate a calendar entry on Microsoft Outlook web interface
as follows:

[image]

or in the new UI:

[image]